# VBScript object required

Tags: vbscript, hta

```
Option Explicit 
Dim output, ProxyEnable, ProxyServer, wshShell, doc

Sub Window_onLoad
    loadProxySettings()
End Sub 

Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ProxyEnable = wshShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable")
ProxyServer = wshShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer")

Function loadProxySettings()
    If ProxyEnable = 1 Then
        proxyStatus.className = "enabled"
        proxyStatus.innerHTML = "Proxy aktiv"

        toggleProxyButton.value = "Proxy deaktivieren"

        proxyServer.value = ProxyServer
    Else
        proxyStatus.className = "disabled"
        proxyStatus.innerHTML = "Proxy deaktiviert"

        toggleProxyButton.value = "Proxy aktivieren"

        proxyServer.value = ProxyServer
    End If 
End Function
```

Just can't find the problem why this is giving me the error:

> Object required "ProxyStatus"

*(and yes I have a `span` element with the `id` of `proxyStatus`)*

Comment: `Set doc = document` seems to be setting `doc` equal to something which is uninitialized.

Comment: hmm tried it too, but still the same.. thats why i am so irritated..hmm thanks tho

Comment: Edit your code to show what `doc` is being set equal to.

Comment: The variable `document` is still not initialized in your code. Where do you expect its content to come from? Is this perhaps used in an ASP or HTA?

Comment: yap.. its a hta.. it should be already declerated oa?

Comment: @Steve Would have been useful to mention that in the question, save people second guessing.

Comment: @Lankymart .. sry for that .. pretty late and forgot about it

Comment: Do you need those `Set` commands on existing DOM objects?

Comment: Go back to using `ProxyStatus = document.getElementById("proxyStatus")` just without the `Set` on front you are not instantiating an object just referencing an existing one in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back to [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35639540/3)

```
Set ProxyStatus = document.getElementById("proxyStatus")
Set ToggleProxyButton = document.getElementById("toggleProxy")
Set ProxyServerInput = document.getElementById("proxyServer")
```

The only mistake here as long as the HTML is correctly formed is the use of `Set` when you are just referencing existing objects in the DOM. Try removing the `Set` from these lines like this;

```
ProxyStatus = document.getElementById("proxyStatus")
ToggleProxyButton = document.getElementById("toggleProxy")
ProxyServerInput = document.getElementById("proxyServer")
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTAs you can use the ID of ID'd elements like variables, i.e. if you have an element like this:

```html
<p>foo <span id="proxyStatus">something</span> bar</p>
```

you should be able to use it in your code like this without having to do anything first:

```vb
MsgBox proxyStatus.innerText
```

Comment: thanks for that.. i know but it doesn't work either .. still the same, it seems that the getElementById doesn't find the element in the DOM..

Comment: @steve If it's not finding the DOM elements it may not see the HTML as a valid structure, try validating the HTML.

Comment: Did you remove the `getElementById()` statements, so they don't mess up existing variables? Does your HTML contain frames or iframes?